# Is there any way to read csv file into an array on specific index in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, csv, methods

Is there any way to read csv file into an array on specific index?
I'm working on a project so i have to concatenate a single row from csv file with output.
but i cant find a way to read a specific row. There are different ways for columns but not for rows(i cant find)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Instead of simply asking how to accomplish something, could you also add what you have tried? Posting code is one of the best ways to get help and add context to your question. 

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Commons CSV](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.8).

Should be as simple as something like:

```java
package com.com.data.load;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class RowReader {

    public static String[] readRow(final File file, final int row) throws Exception {
        try (final FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
             final CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(reader)) {

            final Stream<CSVRecord> stream = StreamSupport.stream(parser.spliterator(), false);

            // row - 1 since header column
            final CSVRecord record =  stream.skip(row - 1).limit(1).findFirst().orElse(null);

            if (record == null) {
                return new String[] {};
            }

            final String[] result = new String[record.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                result[i] = record.get(i);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just copied the code directly from my IDE after testing it.  It works fine.

Comment: i dont what is the problem. Whatever thanks for your help.

Comment: I've included the imports and converted to an array as requested.  This is working just fine, I'd guess the problem is you haven't included the linked library in your project.